# Docker container redirecting

Tags: docker

Hi i have a url called :

> https://wona.logs.co.za

And i need it to redirect to the speciic docker container at port 3000

> ( http://156.43.123.226:3000)

However when i try link https://wona.logs.co.za to 156.43.123.226:3000 i cannot enter a port number in the redirection to specify my docker container

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things that do not fit.

- you try to redirect https traffic to an http endpoint. That won't wortk
- you are trying to directly redirect to another port (from 443, to 3000). That won't work either.

**Solution**

Create a proxy container. e.g. nginx that serves port 80 / 443 and redirects traffic to your application on port 3000. I recommend that you do not directly expose your application - only via the proxy.

Once you have a proxy container that listens to the same ports you can easily use the redirect as you described.

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks the current setup of docker on mentioned server. From what i understood, is you already have docker running with orchestrator and a proxy server for main domain, and now you want to put up a subdomain which forwards traffic to one specific container.

For this, you need to spin an image of your application which listens on port 3000, add an entry in proxy server to forward traffic to your new container. Handle the ssl handshaking at proxy level.